# Couchbase network error when using get & set in bucket.js

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I have this simple js script:

```
var cb = require('couchbase');
var bucket;
var connectionSettings = {
                            'user':'test-bucket',
                            'password':'test',
                            'hosts':['localhost:8091'],
                            'bucket':'test-bucket'
                         };

cb.connect(connectionSettings, function(e, bucket) {

    if (e) {

        errorHandler('connect', e);

    } else {

        console.log('Connection established!');

        bucket.get('testObject', function(e, doc) {
            if(e) {
                errorHandler('get', e);
            } else {
                console.log(doc);
            }       
        });

    }

});

function errorHandler(from, e) {

    console.log('Function: ' + from);
    console.log(e.message);
    console.log(e.stack);

}
```

After executing it a connection is being established, but when I try to get the document with id 'a' in this test case I get the following error:

```
syd@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop$ node test.js
Connection established!
Function: get
Network error
Error: Network error
    at makeError (/home/syd/node_modules/couchbase/lib/bucket.js:578:18)
    at getParsedHandler (/home/syd/node_modules/couchbase/lib/bucket.js:625:17)
node: ../src/ioplugin.cc:496: virtual int Couchnode::IoOps::updateEvent(lcb_socket_t, void*, short int, void*, void (*)(lcb_socket_t, short int, void*)): Assertion `socket != __null' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Furthermore here are the code snippets where these errors occur in bucket.js.

578:

```
function makeError(conn, errorCode) {
    // Early-out for success
    if (errorCode == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    // Build a standard NodeJS Error object with the passed errorCode
    var errObj = new Error(conn.strError(errorCode)); // <- 578 error here
    errObj.code = errorCode;
    return errObj;
}
```

625:

```
function getParsedHandler(data, errorCode, key, cas, flags, value) {
    // if it looks like it might be JSON, try to parse it
    if (/[\{\[]/.test(value)) {
        try {
            value = JSON.parse(value);
        } catch (e) {
        // console.log("JSON.parse error", e, value)
        }
    }
    var error = makeError(data[1], errorCode); // <- 625 error here
    data[0](error, value, {
        id : key,
        cas: cas,
        flags : flags
    });
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening ?
P.S. I have no issues mining data from PHP.

Comment: Why are you declaring `var bucket = null;`? And check couchbase is running or not? Please update further details...

Comment: First: Are you shure that you have no network issues (i.e. filtered ports, ips by firewall)? And second: try to remove all unused params (like user and password) from couchbase config json or set user var to your bucket name (i.e. "default").

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni It doesn't matter bucket gets the database handle uppon connection it doesn't remain null I checked it.

Comment: @m03geek no firewall issues & filtered ports. I have also done what you suggest. Also this has been tested on various buckets with and without authentication.

Comment: What version of libcouchbase did you use?

Comment: @m03geek latest just downloaded and re-installed today

Comment: @Panagiotis George Raditsas can you try older version (i.e. 2.0.7). I've added some download links in [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36085) in your second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails for the same reason as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374104/couchbase-network-error-16-socket-assertion-failed-in-node-js). Downgrading libcouchbase to 2.0.7 should solve issue.

UPD: "Fixed" in new couchbase nodejs library release 1.0.0-beta.